# Need for float __len__, not integer

Tags: python

For my purpose, I created a class that keeps an object.

The real length of that object is float, not integer. There can be 2 objects that differ by -- say .00001, and the shortest is the best for me.

For convenience I defined a `__len__` method inside the class to be able to call len(obj).

However, python does not allow me for `__len__` to return float, only integer.

I thought to return int(real_length * 10**K), for a given K.

Is there a better solution -- to work with floating point lengths of a class object?

EDIT:

In my class I have points in n-dimensional space, and I consider the distance between points, which is a real number, not an integer.

Could I make use of **len** function somehow ?

Comment: I think in this case you should just define another function.

Comment: `__len__` should return the length of the object (which is assumed to be a collection of some sort). If you need to rely on `__len__` for truthyness, define your own `len` method (or `length` property) and then use `__nonzero__`/`__bool__`.

Comment: I agree with @kabie... the `len` of a number makes little sense. The builtin `int` uses `bit_length ()` for instance which reads as to what exactly it means

Comment: Your objects 'length' doesn't seem to refer to the same notion as `len()` -> int : _the number of items of a sequence or mapping._
Can you clarify as to what exactly length is for your object? Could it possibly be something like a score?

Comment: The number of points does not matter, it matters only the distances between them.

Comment: I defined __len__ and I rounded to the lower integer -- however, for more precision of computation, I would like to find another solution... and in the same time to make use of len() function, whose meaning is very intuitive in my case...

Comment: @alinsoar If you think the `len` function fits your case, you've completely misunderstood it. Its purpose is explicitly stated to calculate the length of a sequence (which is if course always an integer). Just write a `distance` function which takes two points and returns the distance as a float.

Comment: OK. I knew that. I needed the minimal distance between every 2 points in the class object -- and name that distance the length of the class instance. I understand that this is not possible via `__len__`, so I will not make use of it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds a "string length" feature to a floating point number.   len() on the object gives the length of the number as if it was a string

```
   class mynumber(float):
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.__str__())
        pass    


    a=mynumber(13.7)
    b=mynumber(13.7000001)

    print len(a)
    print len(b)
```

Tested on python 2.7.  Hope this helps

Here's a different answer based on your comment.  It sets up an object that takes two coordinate pairs and then uses the haversine ([Haversine Formula in Python (Bearing and Distance between two GPS points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points)) formula to find the distance betwixt them

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

class mypointpair(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.coord=[]
        pass
    def add_coords(self,a,b):
        self.coord.append((a,b)) 
    def __len__(self):
        return self.haversine(self.coord[0][0], self.coord[0][1], self.coord[1][0], self.coord[1][1])


    def haversine(self,lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
        """
        Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
        on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
        """
        # convert decimal degrees to radians 
        lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
        # haversine formula 
        dlon = lon2 - lon1 
        dlat = lat2 - lat1 
        a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
        c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
        km = 6367 * c
        return km 


pp1=mypointpair()
pp1.add_coords(53.32055555555556 , -1.7297222222222221 )
pp1.add_coords(53.31861111111111, -1.6997222222222223 )

print len(pp1)
```

Comment: thanks -- but I have real numbers as distances -- the number of points is not important in my case -- it is important only the spatial distance between them.

Comment: Thanks -- I did something identical :). I wanted only to know what solutions do the others have for such case, and to know if the others have better solutions than I had.