# Cosine distance including radius - python specific

Tags: python, r, scipy, trigonometry

In R we have a function, distCosine, within a package Geosphere, [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/geosphere/docs/distCosine)

I am current;y looking to find a similar function in Python, but all I can find is SciPy's implementation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html). This does not include the radius.

Is there a Python based working of this R function? Else I have found some to work write out one [myself](http://www.johndcook.com/python_longitude_latitude.html)

Comment: The linked scipy function is not the same as the Geosphere one

Comment: c.f. this question and answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points)

Comment: I know it wasn't the same - its the only cosine distance I could find in Python. Thanks for the link. Similar solution to the one above, which is o create your own function.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the source code for the R `distCosine` function... just write one in python:

```
from math import acos, sin, cos, pi

def distCosine(p1, p2, r=6378137):
    p1 = [p * pi / 180 for p in p1]
    p2 = [p * pi / 180 for p in p2]

    out = acos(sin(p1[1]) * sin(p2[1]) +\
               cos(p1[1]) * cos(p2[1]) *\
               cos(p1[0] - p2[0])) * r
    return out

distCosine([0, 0], [90, 90])
#  10018754.171394622
```

You might want to add some error checking of sorts, but this works on the example provided by the R package...