# Distance matrix creation using nparray with pdist and squareform

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn, dbscan

I'm trying to cluster using DBSCAN (scikit learn implementation) and location data. My data is in np array format, but to use DBSCAN with Haversine formula I need to create a distance matrix. I'm getting the following error when I try to do this( a 'module' not callable error.) From what i've reading online this is an import error, but I'm pretty sure thats not the case for me. I've created my own haversine distance formula, but I'm sure the error is not with this.

**This is my input data, an np array (ResultArray).**

```
[[ 53.3252628   -6.2644198 ]
[ 53.3287395   -6.2646543 ]
[ 53.33321202  -6.24785807]
[ 53.3261015   -6.2598324 ]
[ 53.325291    -6.2644105 ]
[ 53.3281323   -6.2661467 ]
[ 53.3253074   -6.2644483 ]
[ 53.3388147   -6.2338417 ]
[ 53.3381102   -6.2343826 ]
[ 53.3253074   -6.2644483 ]
[ 53.3228188   -6.2625379 ]
[ 53.3253074   -6.2644483 ]]
```

**And this is the line of code that is erroring.**

```
distance_matrix = sp.spatial.distance.squareform(sp.spatial.distance.pdist
(ResultArray,(lambda u,v: haversine(u,v))))
```

**This is the error message:**

```
File "Location.py", line 48, in <module>
distance_matrix = sp.spatial.distance.squareform(sp.spatial.distance.pdist
(ResArray,(lambda u,v: haversine(u,v))))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 1118, in pdist
dm[k] = dfun(X[i], X[j])
File "Location.py", line 48, in <lambda>
distance_matrix = sp.spatial.distance.squareform(sp.spatial.distance.pdist
(ResArray,(lambda u,v: haversine(u,v))))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I import scipy as sp. ( import scipy as sp )

Comment: Note that ELKI has index acceleration for haversine distance in DBSCAN, using R*-trees. This does not need O(n^2) time and memory. And it also has OPTICS, which is like DBSCAN 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to @TommasoF answer. This answer is wrong: `pdist` allows to choose a custom distance function. I will delete the answer once it is not anymore chosen as the correct answer.

Simply `scipy`'s `pdist` does not allow to pass in a custom distance function. As you can read in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html), you have some options, but haverside distance is not within the list of supported metrics.

(Matlab `pdist` does support the option though, see [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/pdist.html))

you need to do the calculation "manually", i.e. with loops, something like this will work:

```
from numpy import array,zeros

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """  See the link below for a possible implementation """
    pass

#example input (your's, truncated)
ResultArray = array([[ 53.3252628, -6.2644198 ],
                     [ 53.3287395  , -6.2646543 ],
                     [ 53.33321202 , -6.24785807],
                     [ 53.3253074  , -6.2644483 ]])

N = ResultArray.shape[0]
distance_matrix = zeros((N, N))
for i in xrange(N):
    for j in xrange(N):
        lati, loni = ResultArray[i]
        latj, lonj = ResultArray[j]
        distance_matrix[i, j] = haversine(loni, lati, lonj, latj)
        distance_matrix[j, i] = distance_matrix[i, j]

print distance_matrix
[[ 0.          0.38666203  1.41010971  0.00530489]
 [ 0.38666203  0.          1.22043364  0.38163748]
 [ 1.41010971  1.22043364  0.          1.40848782]
 [ 0.00530489  0.38163748  1.40848782  0.        ]]
```

Just for reference, an implementation in Python of Haverside can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points).

Comment: Clearly scipy does allow custom distance functions, as demonstrated this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24387552/2437479)

Comment: Thanks @shreyasgm for pointing this out, after answering I did not read the other answers and never got back here. TheBaywatchKid, can you please choose the answer by TommasoF as the correct one, so that I will be able to delete my answer?

Answer (score 10):

With Scipy you can define a custom distance function as suggested by the documentation at this [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and reported here for convenience:

> ```
> Y = pdist(X, f)
> ```

```
Computes the distance between all pairs of vectors in X using the user supplied 2-arity function f. For example, Euclidean distance between the vectors could be computed as follows:

dm = pdist(X, lambda u, v: np.sqrt(((u-v)**2).sum()))
```

Here I report my version of the code inspired on the code from this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/dlampetest/python/numpy-array-math):

```
from numpy import sin,cos,arctan2,sqrt,pi # import from numpy
# earth's mean radius = 6,371km
EARTHRADIUS = 6371.0

def getDistanceByHaversine(loc1, loc2):
    '''Haversine formula - give coordinates as a 2D numpy array of
    (lat_denter link description hereecimal,lon_decimal) pairs'''
    #      
    # "unpack" our numpy array, this extracts column wise arrays
    lat1 = loc1[1]
    lon1 = loc1[0]
    lat2 = loc2[1]
    lon2 = loc2[0]
    #
    # convert to radians ##### Completely identical
    lon1 = lon1 * pi / 180.0
    lon2 = lon2 * pi / 180.0
    lat1 = lat1 * pi / 180.0
    lat2 = lat2 * pi / 180.0
    #
    # haversine formula #### Same, but atan2 named arctan2 in numpy
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = (sin(dlat/2))**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2.0))**2
    c = 2.0 * arctan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1.0-a))
    km = EARTHRADIUS * c
    return km
```

And calling in the following way:

```
D = spatial.distance.pdist(A, lambda u, v: getDistanceByHaversine(u,v))
```

In my implementation the matrix A has as first column the longitude values and as second column the latitude values expressed in decimal degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can now cluster spatial latitude-longitude data with scikit-learn's DBSCAN and haversine metric without precomputing a distance matrix using scipy.

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=2/6371., min_samples=5, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coordinates))
```

This comes from this tutorial on **[clustering spatial data with scikit-learn DBSCAN](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/)**. In particular, notice that the `eps` value is 2 km divided by 6371 (Earth's radius in km) to convert it to radians. Also, notice that `.fit()` takes coordinates in radian units for the haversine metric.