# Interpolating non-uniformly distributed points on a 3D sphere

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spherical-coordinate

I have several points on the unit sphere that are distributed according to the algorithm described in https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/sphere_equi.pdf (and implemented in the code below). On each of these points, I have a value that in my particular case represents 1 minus a small error. The errors are in `[0, 0.1]` if this is important, so my values are in `[0.9, 1]`.

Sadly, computing the errors is a costly process and I cannot do this for as many points as I want. Still, I want my plots to look like I am plotting something "continuous".
So I want to fit an interpolation function to my data, to be able to sample as many points as I want.

After a little bit of research I found [scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline) which seems to do exactly what I want. But I cannot make it work properly.

**Question:** what can I use to interpolate (spline, linear interpolation, anything would be fine for the moment) my data on the unit sphere? An answer can be either "you misused `scipy.interpolation`, here is the correct way to do this" or "this other function is better suited to your problem".

Sample code that should be executable with `numpy` and `scipy` installed:

```py
import typing as ty

import numpy
import scipy.interpolate


def get_equidistant_points(N: int) -> ty.List[numpy.ndarray]:
    """Generate approximately n points evenly distributed accros the 3-d sphere.

    This function tries to find approximately n points (might be a little less
    or more) that are evenly distributed accros the 3-dimensional unit sphere.

    The algorithm used is described in
    https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/sphere_equi.pdf.
    """
    # Unit sphere
    r = 1

    points: ty.List[numpy.ndarray] = list()

    a = 4 * numpy.pi * r ** 2 / N
    d = numpy.sqrt(a)
    m_v = int(numpy.round(numpy.pi / d))
    d_v = numpy.pi / m_v
    d_phi = a / d_v

    for m in range(m_v):
        v = numpy.pi * (m + 0.5) / m_v
        m_phi = int(numpy.round(2 * numpy.pi * numpy.sin(v) / d_phi))
        for n in range(m_phi):
            phi = 2 * numpy.pi * n / m_phi
            points.append(
                numpy.array(
                    [
                        numpy.sin(v) * numpy.cos(phi),
                        numpy.sin(v) * numpy.sin(phi),
                        numpy.cos(v),
                    ]
                )
            )
    return points


def cartesian2spherical(x: float, y: float, z: float) -> numpy.ndarray:
    r = numpy.linalg.norm([x, y, z])
    theta = numpy.arccos(z / r)
    phi = numpy.arctan2(y, x)
    return numpy.array([r, theta, phi])


n = 100
points = get_equidistant_points(n)
# Random here, but costly in real life.
errors = numpy.random.rand(len(points)) / 10

# Change everything to spherical to use the interpolator from scipy.
ideal_spherical_points = numpy.array([cartesian2spherical(*point) for point in points])
r_interp = 1 - errors
theta_interp = ideal_spherical_points[:, 1]
phi_interp = ideal_spherical_points[:, 2]
# Change phi coordinate from [-pi, pi] to [0, 2pi] to please scipy.
phi_interp[phi_interp < 0] += 2 * numpy.pi

# Create the interpolator.
interpolator = scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline(
    theta_interp, phi_interp, r_interp
)

# Creating the finer theta and phi values for the final plot
theta = numpy.linspace(0, numpy.pi, 100, endpoint=True)
phi = numpy.linspace(0, numpy.pi * 2, 100, endpoint=True)

# Creating the coordinate grid for the unit sphere.
X = numpy.outer(numpy.sin(theta), numpy.cos(phi))
Y = numpy.outer(numpy.sin(theta), numpy.sin(phi))
Z = numpy.outer(numpy.cos(theta), numpy.ones(100))

thetas, phis = numpy.meshgrid(theta, phi)
heatmap = interpolator(thetas, phis)
```

Issue with the code above:

- With the code as-is, I have a

  ```
  ValueError: The required storage space exceeds the available storage space: nxest or nyest too small, or s too small. The weighted least-squares spline corresponds to the current set of knots.
  ```

  that is raised when initialising the `interpolator` instance.
- The issue above seems to say that I should change the value of `s` that is one on the parameters of [scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline). I tested different values of `s` ranging from `0.0001` to `100000`, the code above always raise, either the exception described above or:

  ```
  ValueError: Error code returned by bispev: 10
  ```

---

Edit: I am including my findings here. They can't really be considered as a solution, that is why I am editing and not posting as an answer.

With more research I found this question [Using Radial Basis Functions to Interpolate a Function on a Sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169236/using-radial-basis-functions-to-interpolate-a-function-on-a-sphere). The author has exactly the same problem as me and use a different interpolator: [scipy.interpolate.Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html#scipy.interpolate.Rbf). I changed the above code by replacing the interpolator and plotting:

```py
# Create the interpolator.
interpolator = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(theta_interp, phi_interp, r_interp)

# Creating the finer theta and phi values for the final plot
plot_points = 100
theta = numpy.linspace(0, numpy.pi, plot_points, endpoint=True)
phi = numpy.linspace(0, numpy.pi * 2, plot_points, endpoint=True)

# Creating the coordinate grid for the unit sphere.
X = numpy.outer(numpy.sin(theta), numpy.cos(phi))
Y = numpy.outer(numpy.sin(theta), numpy.sin(phi))
Z = numpy.outer(numpy.cos(theta), numpy.ones(plot_points))

thetas, phis = numpy.meshgrid(theta, phi)
heatmap = interpolator(thetas, phis)


import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

colormap = cm.inferno
normaliser = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=numpy.min(heatmap), vmax=1)
scalar_mappable = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=colormap, norm=normaliser)
scalar_mappable.set_array([])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax.plot_surface(
    X,
    Y,
    Z,
    facecolors=colormap(normaliser(heatmap)),
    alpha=0.7,
    cmap=colormap,
)
plt.colorbar(scalar_mappable)
plt.show()
```

This code runs smoothly and gives the following result:
[image]

The interpolation seems OK **except** on one line that is discontinuous, just like in the question that led me to this class. [One of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40524441/4810787) give the idea of using a different distance, more adapted the the spherical coordinates: the Haversine distance.

```py
def haversine(x1, x2):
    theta1, phi1 = x1
    theta2, phi2 = x2
    return 2 * numpy.arcsin(
        numpy.sqrt(
            numpy.sin((theta2 - theta1) / 2) ** 2
            + numpy.cos(theta1) * numpy.cos(theta2) * numpy.sin((phi2 - phi1) / 2) ** 2
        )
    )


# Create the interpolator.
interpolator = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(theta_interp, phi_interp, r_interp, norm=haversine)
```

which, when executed, gives a warning:

```
LinAlgWarning: Ill-conditioned matrix (rcond=1.33262e-19): result may not be accurate.
  self.nodes = linalg.solve(self.A, self.di)
```

and a result that is not at all the one expected: the interpolated function have values that may go up to `-1` which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Cartesian coordinate** instead of Spherical coordinate.

The default norm parameter (`'euclidean'`) used by [Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html) is sufficient

```py
# interpolation
x, y, z = numpy.array(points).T
interpolator = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, r_interp)

# predict
heatmap = interpolator(X, Y, Z)
```

Here the result:

```py
ax.plot_surface(
    X, Y, Z,
    rstride=1, cstride=1, 
    # or rcount=50, ccount=50,
    facecolors=colormap(normaliser(heatmap)),
    cmap=colormap,
    alpha=0.7, shade=False
)
ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')
```

[image]

You can also use a cosine distance if you want (norm parameter):

```py
def cosine(XA, XB):
    if XA.ndim == 1:
        XA = numpy.expand_dims(XA, axis=0)
    if XB.ndim == 1:
        XB = numpy.expand_dims(XB, axis=0)
    return scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(XA, XB)
```

[image: Cosine Distance]

In order to better see the differences,
I stacked the two images, substracted them and inverted the layer.
[image]