# Relation between radius in latitude and meters (Basemap)

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


plt.figure(1)
map = Basemap(projection='merc',
resolution='l',
llcrnrlat=44.0,
llcrnrlon=5.0,
urcrnrlat=57.0,
urcrnrlon=17)
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
map.fillcontinents(color='lightgray')
map.drawmapboundary()

long1 = np.array([ 13.404954,  11.581981,   9.993682,   8.682127,   6.960279,
6.773456,   9.182932,  12.373075,  13.737262,  11.07675 ,
7.465298,   7.011555,  12.099147,   9.73201 ,   7.628279,
8.801694,  10.52677 ,   8.466039,   8.239761,  10.89779 ,
8.403653,   8.532471,   7.098207,   7.216236,   9.987608,
7.626135,  11.627624,   6.852038,  10.686559,   8.047179,
8.247253,   6.083887,   7.588996,   9.953355,  10.122765])

lat1 = np.array([ 52.520007,  48.135125,  53.551085,  50.110922,  50.937531,
51.227741,  48.775846,  51.339695,  51.050409,  49.45203 ,
51.513587,  51.455643,  54.092441,  52.375892,  51.36591 ,
53.079296,  52.268874,  49.487459,  50.078218,  48.370545,
49.00689 ,  52.030228,  50.73743 ,  51.481845,  48.401082,
51.960665,  52.120533,  51.47512 ,  53.865467,  52.279911,
49.992862,  50.775346,  50.356943,  49.791304,  54.323293])

x, y = map(long1, lat1)
map.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.show()
```

with

```
nylat = 52.520007; nylon = 13.404954
lonlat = 48.135125; lonlon = 11.581981
m.drawgreatcircle(nylon,nylat,lonlon,lonlat,linewidth=2,color='b')
```

i can draw a straight line between two points. Is this the correct way?

The question is how can i draw a circle around a point. I want to fill the inner of the circle with a light red, so i can see all points and lines which are underneath the circle.

I want to be able to adjust the radius of the circle. A Example would be 60 km for the radius!

**UPDATE**

I need the tissot function:

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

```
x0, y0 = 35, -50
R = 5

m = Basemap(width=8000000,height=7000000, resolution='l',projection='aea', 
    lat_1=-40.,lat_2=-60,lon_0=35,lat_0=-50)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.tissot(x0, y0, R, 100, facecolor='g', alpha=0.5)
```

In the documentary it is written:

> tissot(lon_0, lat_0, radius_deg, npts, ax=None, **kwargs)
>
> Draw a polygon centered at lon_0,lat_0. The polygon approximates a
>   circle on the surface of the earth with radius radius_deg degrees
>   latitude along longitude lon_0, made up of npts vertices. The polygon
>   represents a Tissot’s indicatrix
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot’s_Indicatrix), which when drawn
>   on a map shows the distortion inherent in the map projection.

I need to get a relation between radius_deg and kilometers or meters. How is the relation, does anyone know?

Answer (score 4):

That relationship is called the [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula; it gives the relationship between two points on a spherical surface and the *spherical* distance between them.

An implementation of it is written [elsewhere on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4913653/2476444).

To plot a *projected* circle with Basemap's `tissot`, you'll want to solve the Haversine for a `(lon, lat)` pair that is the desired radius of the circle away from the center `(c_lon, c_lat)` pair. Because of `tissot`'s definition, it is easier to solve for `lat` in the equation `radius = Haversine(c_lon, c_lat, c_lon, lat)`, so using equal longitudes because the plotted circle will have a radius equal to that latitude difference.

In your case, that is simple:

```
def radius_for_tissot(dist_km):
    return np.rad2deg(dist_km/6367.)

lon0, lat0 = 11, (44+57)/2.
mymap.tissot(lon0, lat0, radius_for_tissot(100),
    256, facecolor='b', alpha=0.5)  # places a Tissot circle with radius 100km in Germany
```