# Haversine Python Package in Django ORM query

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm, haversine

I'm working in a Django App that stores `lat` and `lng` for users. I need to find nearby events for users based on their previously-defined radius. For both `Users` and `Events`, I store Latitude and Longitude in a MySQL database.

I found an example of a [raw query](http://andilabs.github.io/django/devops/tools/postgres/postgis/2015/01/31/postgis-geodjango-english.html) that implements the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). There is also a [`haversine` package for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/haversine/0.4.2). How do I use the `haversine` package in a regular Django query?

Comment: have you tried using it?

Comment: @MattO'Brien I don't know how to integrate haversine's functions in a Django query.

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead and add this function to my code:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
```

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points) is also related.

Comment: I also found this, but how to use it a django's query?