# DBSCAN for plotting clusters of coordinate data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have an array of coordinate data (in Web Mercator Eastings and Northings, thus in metres) that looks like this:

```
array([[ -232372.201264,  6785082.61011 ],
   [ -233396.451899,  6784865.49884 ],
   [ -234045.110572,  6784642.2575  ],
   ..., 
   [ -234473.356653,  6778646.81953 ],
   [ -234918.300657,  6778772.69366 ],
   [ -230900.668915,  6778369.2902  ]])
```

This array is stored as the variable 'coords'.

I am attempting to compute - and then plot - the clusters within this dataset using Scikit Learn and DBSCAN (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579213/dbscan-for-clustering-of-geographic-location-data) post for getting me this far).

The code I am using is taken from [this](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/) tutorial, however I get an attribute error. Code and error shown below:

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.2, min_samples=1, metric="precomputed")
cluster_labels = db.labels_
num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))
clusters = pd.Series([coords[cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
print('Number of clusters: {}'.format(num_clusters))
```

...

```
AttributeError: 'DBSCAN' object has no attribute 'labels_'
```

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: @Grr I'm using v0.18.1

Comment: Web Mercator is **not in meters** but in pixels at the given zoom level? Also, it does not work at the 180 degree line... and you get substantial error because of the distortion.

Comment: Pick two cities east-west of each other, e.g., New York and San Francisco, and check their distance!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse the Eastings and Northings, which I was referring to, are values in metres: https://epsg.io/3857

Comment: OK, so it seems to be the zoom level set to match the equator. Did you try the distance I mentioned, to get a feeling of how big your errors are? I'd rather not rely on the eastings unless close to the equator. Because I'd assume you get a distance some 1.4x as large as the *actual* distance, and that is a quite substantial error. Mercator projections are unsuitable for distances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing `fit`:

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.2, min_samples=1, metric="precomputed")
db.fit(data)
cluster_labels = db.labels_
num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))
clusters = pd.Series([coords[cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
print('Number of clusters: {}'.format(num_clusters))
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm now getting a new error:

    ValueError: Precomputed metric requires shape (n_queries, n_indexed). Got (10487, 2) for 10487 indexed.

Comment: remove `metric="precomputed"`

Comment: Seems to work - thank you! How does removing "precomputed" affect the outcome? Apologies for the n00b questions; this is all new to me. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: From docs:  If metric is “precomputed”, X is assumed to be a distance matrix and must be square. X may be a sparse matrix, in which case only “nonzero” elements may be considered neighbors for DBSCAN.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call it like

```
db=DBSCAN(eps=0.2, min_samples=1, metric="precomputed").fit(mymatrix)
```

(please notice the `fit()` function)