# Get diagonal squares coordinates in numpy distance symmetric matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cosine-similarity, distance-matrix

How to get the coordinates of the big rectangles that line on the diagonal.

For example yellow [0,615], [615,1438], [1438,1526]

```py
import numpy as np; 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

df = pd.DataFrame(array) # array is image numpy
df.shape #(1526, 360)
s = cosine_similarity(df) #(1526, 1526)
plt.matshow(s)
```

[image: matrix cosine distance]

i try get peaks in first row, but have noise information

```
speak = 1-s[0]

peaks, _ = find_peaks(speak, distance=160, height=0.1)
print(peaks, len(peaks))
np.diff(peaks)

plt.plot(speak)
plt.plot(peaks, speak[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

[image: one row histogram]

Update, add another example
And upload to colab full script https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hyDIDs-QjLjD2mVIX4nNOXOcvCZY4O2c?usp=sharing

[image: noise example]
[image: example2]

Comment: What is shape of s?

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma (1526,1526)

Comment: provide a sample of s to work on. or provide a code to produce it

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma upload dataframe to csv https://dropmefiles.com/CxWey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve with [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) clustering (find in same question [DBSCAN for clustering of geographic location data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579213/dbscan-for-clustering-of-geographic-location-data))

```py
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

clustering = DBSCAN(eps=.5, min_samples=10).fit_predict(s)

peaks = np.where(clustering[:-1] != clustering[1:])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.diag(df)` to get a list of diagonal elements. Check when value crosses threshold if the color in your screenshot stands for below/above some value, probably zero.

Comment: need diagonal of 's = cosine_similarity(df)', then it turns out there will always be values equal to 1

Comment: Then do a loop through the `np.diag(s)`. Without your values I do not know what the color in your plot mean.

Comment: @Aramkus yes you are right, but on the distance matrix the diagonal values always correspond to the element itself, there is no useful information there.
It is necessary to look exactly at the area of large squares lying on the diagonal.
I upload dataframe  to csv dropmefiles.com/CxWey

Comment: If matplotlib plots these areas the same color, the values within them are rather similar, so diagonal should contain all the information. You can try to find points where your diagonal array intersect a rolling average of itself. In such places values in `s` rapidly change.

Comment: @Aramkus I gave only one example, colors do not really matter, and the squares can be different ... I'm looking for an algorithm maybe something like classification or clustering

Comment: @Aramkus add another example to post

Comment: @rustams What do you expect output in 2nd and 3rd examples?

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma in 2 [0,340][340,350], in 3 [0,420],[420,1000] maybe

Comment: Check my answer, and change the filter value, you will get your output. @rustams

Comment: @rustams Add value of s[600:630, 600:630], s[1430:1460, 1430:1460] in your question to help you get the factor value(of my answer), if you are unable to get it.

Answer (score 1):

All the diagonal elements of cosine_similarity are same. So you should look for changes in nearby values.

You could try this:

```
factor = 1.01
look_nearby = 1

changes = []
for i in range(look_nearby, s.shape[0]-look_nearby):
    if s[i, i+look_nearby] > factor*s[i, i-look_nearby] or factor*s[i, i+look_nearby] < s[i, i-look_nearby]:
        changes.append(i)
        
print(changes)
```

Set the `factor` value according to your preference (as you do not want (1200, 1200) in the output of 1st image) and according to the values of s.

Comment: ```[607, 608, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 1380, 1381, 1382, 1383, 1385, 1394, 1395, 1396, 1397, 1398, 1399, 1400, 1401, 1402, 1430, 1431, 1432, 1433, 1434, 1435, 1436, 1437, 1440, 1441, 1442, 1443, 1444, 1445, 1447, 1448, 1449, 1450, 1451, 1452, 1453, 1454, 1455, 1456, 1457, 1458, 1459, 1460, 1461, 1463, 1464, 1465, 1466, 1467, 1468, 1469, 1470, 1471, 1473, 1479, 1480, 1481, 1482, 1483, 1484, 1485, 1486, 1487, 1488.......1519, 1520, 1521, 1522, 1524]```  thanks a lot, but maybe I could not put the question correctly ... I need large intervals, as bright as possible and not all

Comment: Yes, to get large intervals, you should change the factor value, try increasing it to 2 or 1.5 or other values or decrease it to 0.5 or other. I cannot tell the factor value without seeing actual data of s

Comment: Upload to colad full example https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hyDIDs-QjLjD2mVIX4nNOXOcvCZY4O2c?usp=sharing

Comment: This Colab notebook runs fine, what's the error? And what are you expecting as output for the image

Comment: no error, it works almost well ... I don't like the fact that I now use the first row to find the peaks and not the diagonal histogram.
You can make an average, histogram on the first, middle, last row and get the average peaks. But it seems to me not optimal.

Comment: [Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hyDIDs-QjLjD2mVIX4nNOXOcvCZY4O2c?usp=sharing) I have added, how could you use the code given in answer for various factor values. Since I don't get, what do you want to do with that or what do you want the output (provide some proper range that this rectangle is big and this is less), I can't help much.