# To write the distance between coordinates to a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to calculate the distance between coordinates saved in a CSV file and write the result to a new CSV file that has a new column called distance and the other columns from the parent file. can someone help me fix this?

The CSV contains the following data:

```
LAT,LON,CELL
6.930338363,3.723996158,UIAA001_S1
6.930338363,3.723996158,UIAA001_S2
6.930338363,3.723996158,UIAA001_S3
6.73186,3.41586,UIBG008_S1
6.73186,3.41586,UIBG008_S2
6.73186,3.41586,UIBG008_S3
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: You could make use of the haversine calculation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points - As for writing back to a csv file, that should be straight forward and a simple Google search will reveal many answers

Comment: am trying to paste the code here but it keeps saying error

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us a sample output.