# How to check if coordinate inside certain area Python

Tags: python, location, coordinates, latitude-longitude, area

Lets say I have 2 kind of coordinate, first called `center_point` and second called `test_point`. I want to know if `test_point` coordinate is inside near or not to `center_point` coordinate by applying `radius` threshold. If I write it, its like:

```
center_point = [{'lat': -7.7940023, 'lng': 110.3656535}]
test_point = [{'lat': -7.79457, 'lng': 110.36563}]

radius = 5 # in kilometer
```

How to check if the `test_point` inside or outside the radius from `center_point` in Python? how I perform this kind task in Python?

Result expected will say that `test_point` inside or outside the `radius` from `center_point` coordinate.

Comment: Calculate distance using haversine formula http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points and see if it is less than r

Comment: hi @user1753919 thanks, it works.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

from recommendation of @user1753919 in his/her comment, I got the answer here: [Haversine Formula in Python (Bearing and Distance between two GPS points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points)

final code:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r

center_point = [{'lat': -7.7940023, 'lng': 110.3656535}]
test_point = [{'lat': -7.79457, 'lng': 110.36563}]

lat1 = center_point[0]['lat']
lon1 = center_point[0]['lng']
lat2 = test_point[0]['lat']
lon2 = test_point[0]['lng']

radius = 1.00 # in kilometer

a = haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)

print('Distance (km) : ', a)
if a <= radius:
    print('Inside the area')
else:
    print('Outside the area')
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Works great for our project :)

Answer (score 21):

[GeoPy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance) can handle it gracefully:

```
from geopy import distance

center_point = [{'lat': -7.7940023, 'lng': 110.3656535}]
test_point = [{'lat': -7.79457, 'lng': 110.36563}]
radius = 5 # in kilometer

center_point_tuple = tuple(center_point[0].values()) # (-7.7940023, 110.3656535)
test_point_tuple = tuple(test_point[0].values()) # (-7.79457, 110.36563)

dis = distance.distance(center_point_tuple, test_point_tuple).km
print("Distance: {}".format(dis)) # Distance: 0.0628380925748918

if dis <= radius:
    print("{} point is inside the {} km radius from {} coordinate".format(test_point_tuple, radius, center_point_tuple))
else:
    print("{} point is outside the {} km radius from {} coordinate".format(test_point_tuple, radius, center_point_tuple))
```

or if you need to know the great circle distance:

```
dis = distance.great_circle(center_point_tuple, test_point_tuple).km
print("Distance: {}".format(dis)) # Distance: 0.0631785164583489
```

Comment: That's the format that was in the question. It's also more explicit where is latitude and where is longitude.

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry. You're right. That makes sense. I wanted to update the previous comment but I can't do that. So I'm gonna delete it

Answer (score 2):

```
from math import sqrt
a = center_point[0]['lat'] - test_point[0]['lat']
b = center_point[0]['lng'] - test_point[0]['lng']
c = sqrt(a * a  +  b * b)
if (c < radius):
        print("inside")
else:
        print("outside")
```

Comment: hi, whats the `aa` and `bb` inside `c = math.sqrt(aa + bb)` refer to?

Comment: Sorry, bad formatting. I edited it to be more clear.

Comment: how can this be used to be tested on the entire dataframe with less computational cost?

Comment: This should be done more efficiently with a KDTree or kNearestNeighbors algorithm, but I haven't found any examples that actually work with lat-lon points yet.