# Lat/long python type conversion error unable to convert to float (2nd attempt)

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, location

Right, I made a hash of asking this question when I was fried at the back end of yesterday so I'm doing it properly now.

The block below converts some data into lat/long info and then there's an if statement where I can grab certain parts of a large JSON file which there's a section of below.

What I want to do it take the forklift data, convert it's position (which is x and y meters from a known lat/long into an actual lat/long using Pythagoras) and then use the if statement to only print certain parts of the JSON (name, time, converted position).  The JSON consists of people & machine info and I want to separate them.

```
"id": "b4994c877c9c",
"name": "forklift_0001",  <---forklift data used in IF statement
"areaId": "Tracking001",
"areaName": "hall_1",
"color": "#FF0000",
"coordinateSystemId": "CoordSys001",
"coordinateSystemName": null,
"covarianceMatrix": [
    0.47,
    0.06,
    0.06,
    0.61
],
"position": [
    33.86,    <---position data converted from known lat/long, X then Y.
    33.07,
    2.15
],
"positionAccuracy": 0.36,
"positionTS": 1489363199493,
"smoothedPosition": [
    33.96,
    33.13,
    2.15
],
"zones": [
    {
        "id": "Zone001",
        "name": "Halli1"
```

The problem I have seems to be that the first print statement is a float and to be able to pass the result into the if statement it needs to be a string.

Here's the code I have

```
for f in file_list:
print('Input file: ' + f) # Replace with desired operations

with open(f, 'r') as f:

    distros = json.load(f)
    output_file = 'forklift_0001_parse' + str(output_nr) + '.csv' #output file name may be changed

    with open(output_file, 'w') as text_file:
        for distro in distros:      
            position = distro['position']
            R = 6378.1 #Radius of the Earth
            brng = 1.57 #Bearing is 90 degrees converted to radians.
            d = math.sqrt((position[0]*position[0] + position[1]*position[1]) + 0.00303) #Pythagoras formula to work distance from ref lat/long point

            lat1 = math.radians(60.477719)#Reference lat point 
            lon1 = math.radians(26.941589)#Reference long point 

            lat2 = math.asin(math.sin(lat1)*math.cos(d/R) + 
            math.cos(lat1)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(brng))

            lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(brng)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(lat1),
            math.cos(d/R)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2))

            lat2 = math.degrees(lat2)
            lon2 = math.degrees(lon2)
            print((lat2, lon2), file=text_file) 

            if distro['name'].startswith(('Trukki_0001')): #choose desired parameters to be parsed
                print (str(distro['name']))

                print(distro['name'] + ',' + str(distro['positionTS']) + ',' + str(distro['position']) + ',' + str(distro['lat2']), file=text_file)
                #replace desired roots between square brackets

    print('Output written to file: ' + output_file)
    output_nr = output_nr + 1
```

The error this gives is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "position_parse_3.py", line 45, in <module>
print(distro['name'] + ',' + str(distro['positionTS']) + ',' + 
str(distro['position']) + ',' + str(distro['lat2']), file=text_file)
KeyError: 'lat2'
```

I am completely stuck and have tried a few ways to solve it. I've tried to convert them from floats earlier in the script that first prints statement but that did not work (can't convert them implicitly) and I am also concerned I'll lose the accuracy of the result.

If someone could help me pass the result of the lat/long calculation into the IF statement, i would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Ok, the inclusion of the JSON makes this a much better starting point for this :) But your issue seems to still be misdiagnosed. Even if you did pass the result of your calculation as a key, you won't get this to work because there are _no_ keys in that dictionary that resemble a float.

Comment: You want something like snap-to-grid here as the wider issue you're tackling? If so, the JSON is perhaps back-to-front for what you want, so we'll need to do some transformation beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This is tough to answer because I think you're going about the issue the wrong way. If we take a step back and define a more simple dictionary:

```
json_response = {'loc_a': [20, 30], 'loc_b': [10, 50], 'loc_c': [30, 40]}
```

The only valid ways to access the data by key would be `json_response['loc_a']`, `json_response['loc_b']` or `json_response['loc_c']`. There are no keys in that dictionary that resemble a numerical value; they're contained in the *values* stored against the keys. The same applies to your current situation; there are *no* numerical-looking keys, so it's not possible to do what you want to do. Even if there were, you'll be confronted with rounding errors etc. if you converted your lat/long to a string to use as a key.

You've mentioned a type error in both questions, but what you're getting is `KeyError`. These are very different things, and there's no reason to believe that the `KeyError` is due to typing at all. `json_response[40]` and `json_response["40"]` still won't work in my example. To answer the actual question, you would use `+ str(distro[str(lat2)])` to use the string representation of your float, but it still *won't work* because of the aforementioned issue.

Your problem is actually quite a lot more complex. Searching for those lat/longs in a dictionary is not simple. I can't think of a neat way of storing these locations; it looks like you'll have to traverse the JSON each time. There are certainly more efficient ways of going about this, but for illustration:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4913653/4799172
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r


json_response = {'loc_a': [20, 30], 'loc_b': [10, 50], 'loc_c': [30, 40]}

calculated_lat = 35
calculated_lon = 40

closest_match = None
closest_distance = 10000000

for location, coordinates in json_response.items():
    distance = haversine(calculated_lat, coordinates[0], calculated_lon, 
                         coordinates[1])
    if distance < closest_distance:
        closest_match = location
        closest_distance = distance

print(closest_match)
```

*Now* you have at least a key that does exist in `json_response` in order to filter to the data you're interested in.

Comment: You're the guy I annoyed yesterday. sorry about that.  I am completely open to approaching it a new way. I'll see what I can do with what you've suggested.

Comment: @exmatelote haha, yes, but you didn't really annoy me. But your new question confirmed my suspicion to me that I had yesterday so I'm shooting for an answer. I think you're underestimating the complexity of what you're trying to do, and this type issue business is a red herring for you.

Comment: I've figured out how to do it with some help from a friend.  I wrote a function to do the maths and then a for loop with an if statement.  There's a problem with the maths I am still working through but when I get that right i'll post what I did.

Comment: @exmatelote "I wrote a function to do the maths and then a for loop with an if statement." is exactly what is in my answer.