# Approximate GPS Value in Python

Tags: python, math, gps, coordinates

How can I do an approximate search for a "latitude, longitude" coordinate value in a "file.txt" list in Python?

### Value

37.04508, -95.57605

### file.txt

`37.04278, -95.58895
37.04369, -95.58592
37.04369, -95.58582
37.04376, -95.58557
37.04376, -95.58546
37.04415, -95.58429
37.0443, -95.5839
37.04446, -95.58346
37.04461, -95.58305
37.04502, -95.58204
37.04516, -95.58184
37.04572, -95.58139
37.0459, -95.58127
37.04565, -95.58073
37.04546, -95.58033
37.04516, -95.57948
37.04508, -95.57914
37.04494, -95.57842
37.04483, -95.5771
37.0448, -95.57674
37.04474, -95.57606
37.04467, -95.57534
37.04462, -95.57474
37.04458, -95.57396
37.04454, -95.57274
37.04452, -95.57233
37.04453, -95.5722
37.0445, -95.57164
37.04448, -95.57122
37.04444, -95.57054
37.04432, -95.56845
37.04432, -95.56834
37.04424, -95.5668
37.04416, -95.56545
37.044, -95.56251
37.04396, -95.5618`

### Expected Result

37.04508, -95.57914

### Additional Information (if possible)

Line 17

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: You can try just going through the list and then looking for the *closest* value. What have you tried?

Comment: You could use the [Haversine formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is compute the distance between each coordinate then check if that is the closest:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points
def compute_distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
  lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
  dlon = lon2 - lon1
  dlat = lat2 - lat1 
  a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
  c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
  r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
  return c * r

def search_closest(to_find, coordinates):
  closest_coord = (0, 0)
  closest_distance = compute_distance(coordinates[0][1], coordinates[0][0], to_find[1], to_find[0])
  for coord in coordinates:
    current_distance = compute_distance(coord[1], coord[0], to_find[1], to_find[0])
    if closest_distance > current_distance:
      closest_coord = coord
      closest_distance = current_distance
  return closest_coord

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Placeholder for files.txt content
  coordinates = [
    (37.04278, -95.58895),
    (37.04369, -95.58592),
    (37.04369, -95.58582),
    (37.04376, -95.58557),
    (37.04376, -95.58546),
    (37.04415, -95.58429),
    (37.0443, -95.5839),
    (37.04446, -95.58346),
    (37.04461, -95.58305),
    (37.04502, -95.58204),
    (37.04516, -95.58184),
    (37.04572, -95.58139),
    (37.0459, -95.58127),
    (37.04565, -95.58073),
    (37.04546, -95.58033),
    (37.04516, -95.57948),
    (37.04508, -95.57914),
    (37.04494, -95.57842),
    (37.04483, -95.5771),
    (37.0448, -95.57674),
    (37.04474, -95.57606),
    (37.04467, -95.57534),
    (37.04462, -95.57474),
    (37.04458, -95.57396),
    (37.04454, -95.57274),
    (37.04452, -95.57233),
    (37.04453, -95.5722),
    (37.0445, -95.57164),
    (37.04448, -95.57122),
    (37.04444, -95.57054),
    (37.04432, -95.56845),
    (37.04432, -95.56834),
    (37.04424, -95.5668),
    (37.04416, -95.56545),
    (37.044, -95.56251),
    (37.04396, -95.5618)
  ]

  to_find = (37.04508, -95.57605)

  closest = search_closest(to_find, coordinates)

  print(closest)
```

**Edit:** Used **Haversine** to compute distance

Answer (score 0):

Used a different approach to fixatd but this works aswell opening the txt file you requested.

```
import sys, os
import math

coords = open('coords.txt').read().split("\n")
x=[]
y=[]
for r in coords:
    row = r.split(", ")
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])

lowest = None
currentval = None
store = None
value = (37.04508, -95.57605)

for i in range(len(x)):

    currentval = (math.sqrt((((float(x[i]) - value[0])**2) + ((float(y[i]) - value[1])**2))) * 111000)
    if i == 0:
        lowest = currentval
    if currentval < lowest:
        lowest = currentval
        store = (float(x[i]), float(y[i]))
    else:
        continue

print (store)
```