# Why is my code calculating an incorrect distance between transformed coordinates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, distance, geopandas, pyproj

I have a large file of points and I am trying to find the distance between those points and another set of points. Initially I used the `to_crs` function of geopandas to convert the crs so that I can get an accurate distance measure in terms of meters when I do `df.distance(point)`. However, since the file is very large, it took too long just to convert the crs of the file. The code was running for 2 hours and it still did not finish converting. Therefore, I used this code instead.

```
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4808')

for index, row in demand_indo_gdf.iterrows():
    o = Point(row['origin_longitude'], row['origin_latitude'])
    o_proj = Point(transform(inProj, outProj, o.x, o.y))

    for i, r in bus_indo_gdf.iterrows():
        stop = r['geometry']
        stop_proj = Point(transform(inProj, outProj, stop.x, stop.y))
        print ('distance:', o_proj.distance(stop_proj), '\n\n')
```

I thought it may be faster to individually convert the crs and carry out my analysis. For this set of points:

```
o = (106.901024 -6.229162)
stop = (106.804 -6.21861)
```

I converted this EPSG 4326 coordinates to the local projection, EPSG 4808, and got this:

```
o_proj = (0.09183386384156803 -6.229330112968891)
stop_proj = (-0.005201753272169649 -6.218776788266844)
```

This gave a distance measure of 0.09760780527657992. Google maps gave me a distance measure, for coordinates `o` and `stop`, of 10.79km. It looks like the distance measure of my code gives an answer that is 10^-3 times smaller than the actual distance. Why is that so? Is my code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates you are using are in degrees, not in meters.

The `Points` class that you are using probably does not care about this and calculates the cartesian distance between them.

Please use the [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) equation, e.g. the one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4913653/7919597):

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
```

Then your code returns the correct result:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4808')

o = (106.901024, -6.229162)
stop = (106.804, -6.21861)

o_proj = transform(inProj, outProj, o[0], o[1])
stop_proj = transform(inProj, outProj, stop[0], stop[1])

print(haversine(o_proj[0], o_proj[1], stop_proj[0], stop_proj[1]))
```