# quickly compare lots of GPS points with haversine python

Tags: python, haversine

I have 2 lists composed of 100's of GPS coordinates each.

For each element is `list1`, I want to find the element in `list2` it is closest to. To do this, I want to use havesine and python.

```
from haversine import haversine
list1=[45.7, 4.8,45.6,4.8]
list2=[48.8, 2.3,48.8,2.4]
haversine(list1[0:2],list2[0:2])
```

I was thinking of looping through it twice, first through list1, and then again through list2, to compare every single point. I think that is too hard and slow. Is there a way to compute this faster.

A look around SO, I found [Haversine Formula in Python (Bearing and Distance between two GPS points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points), but it does not address many to many comparisons

Comment: "I think that is too hard and slow." Did you test it? 100 x 100 is pretty tiny when calling a general Haversine function. It's manageable to even get real-road distances between locations at that scale

Comment: My real data is 3k by 7k. I set it up and it is still running (~20min), so trying to get some ideas to speed it up.

Comment: Why do you need every distance pair? What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to find the closest point to it

Comment: @alex It would be faster if you only loop through `list1`, and feed `list2` as an array into `haversine` function. The return of the `haversine` function will be an array of all the distances between a point in `list1` and all the points in `list2`, so you can find the minimum one among them.