# Pandas apply operation on each pair of rows

Tags: python, pandas

Same value is repeating in the dataframe column while calculating the distance between langitude and longitude . I have created a dynamic column for finding the distance between every source to destination but all the values of each column is repeating.

```
for a,b,x in zip(df.Longitude,df.Latitude,df.index):
    for c,d in zip(df.Longitude,df.Latitude):
        df['distance_'+str(x)]=haversine(a,b,c,d)
```

[image]

suppose this is the dataframe

```
  index   name   lat     long

    0      a     74.299104  31.481188

    1      b     74.351619  39.481188

    2      c     73.351619  39.481188
```

now i want the expected result like this

```
  index   name   lat          long     distanceA      distanceB     distanceC

    0      a     74.299104  31.481188      0             4.5          2.4

    1      b     74.351619  39.481188     5.7             0           5.8

    2      c     73.351619  39.481188     3.8            1.3           0
```

Comment: create a small dataframe and show your expected results.

Comment: @ScottBoston I am editing the question with the expected result

Comment: @ScottBoston Please check

Comment: How many rows you have and you realize the combination for each row against the other can grow quickly depending on the number of rows? If you are trying to make a feature out of the lat lon for some modelling problem then calculating distance from one fixed point against all should give the model same information as calculating against each pair

Comment: I just have 330 rows so thats not a problem having all the pairs @XXavier

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra ... what `haversine` function are you using?

Comment: Didn’t you already post this question earlier?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this using a self-join to get all combinations:

```
df_m = df.assign(key=1).merge(df.assign(key=1), on='key', suffixes=('','_y'))
df_m['distance'] = df_m.apply(lambda x: haversine((x.lat, x.long),(x.lat_y, x.long_y), 
                                                   unit=Unit.MILES), 
                              axis=1)
df_mat = (df_m.set_index(df.columns.to_list()+['name_y'])['distance']
              .unstack()
              .add_prefix('distance')
              .reset_index())

df.merge(df_mat)
```

Output:

```
  name        lat       long   distancea   distanceb   distancec
0    a  74.299104  31.481188    0.000000  149.269583  167.150147
1    b  74.351619  39.481188  149.269583    0.000000   69.093420
2    c  73.351619  39.481188  167.150147   69.093420    0.000000
```

Comment: @Parfait Great question.   I'm not sure.

Comment: @Parfait I followed an example of how to use haversine from PyPi.  I didn't know any better.

Answer (score 5):

Since the result is mirrored along the diagonal, you can cut the iterations in half:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(index=df['name'], columns=df['name'])

for idx1 in df.index:
    for idx2 in df.index[idx1+1:]:
         name1, lat1, lon1 = df.loc[idx1, ['name', 'lat', 'long']]
         name2, lat2, lon2 = df.loc[idx2, ['name', 'lat', 'long']]

         res.loc[name1, name2] = haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)

res = res.add(res.T, fill_value=0)  # res is upper triangular
```

Comment: As usual.   very smart! +1

Comment: @ScottBoston +1'd you too, I could not think of a non-loopy solution, nice effort B)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a vectorized version of the `haversine` formula and avoid `for` or `apply` loops. For example, assuming you use this [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4913653/1422451), swap out the scalar functions for `numpy` versions:

```
import numpy as np

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a)) 
    r = 3956 # Radius of earth in miles. Use 6371 for kilometers.

    return c * r
```

Then, run cross join with `pivot_table`:

```
cj_df = (df.assign(key=1)
           .merge(df.assign(key=1), on=['key'], suffixes=['', '_'])
        )           

cj_df['distance'] = haversine(cj_df['long'], cj_df['lat'], 
                              cj_df['long_'], cj_df['lat_'])

cj_df.pivot_table(index=['name', 'lat', 'long'],
                  columns = 'name_',
                  values = 'distance',
                  aggfunc = 'max')

# name_                              a           b           c
# name lat       long                                         
# a    74.299104 31.481188    0.000000  149.165464  167.033556
# b    74.351619 39.481188  149.165464    0.000000   69.045225
# c    73.351619 39.481188  167.033556   69.045225    0.000000
```