# Pyspark: cast multiple columns to number

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am applying a method and it is giving error because the cast is not well done

How could I 1) cast all fields in a more efective way,
2) use withColumn just one time and then
3) run the method with numbers (not string):

```
q5 = q4.withColumn("DISTANCE", q4["LOCLAT"].cast(IntegerType()))
q6 = q4.withColumn("DISTANCE", q4["LOCLONG"].cast(IntegerType()))
q7 = q4.withColumn("DISTANCE", q4["LOCLAT2"].cast(IntegerType()))
q8 = q4.withColumn("DISTANCE", q4["LOCLONG2"].cast(IntegerType()))


q9 = (q4.withColumn('distance', haversine('LOCLONG', 'LOCLAT', 'LOCLONG2', 'LOCLAT2')))
```

Thanks!!

Comment: you're overwriting the column 'distance' in each line, and assigining the resulting dataframe to an unused variable. are you sure that's what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but here's how to convert all the 4 columns to integer type and calling the `haversine` function:

```
df = q4.select(
    '*',
    *[F.col(c).cast('int').alias(c + '_int')
      for c in ['LOCLONG', 'LOCLAT', 'LOCLONG2', 'LOCLAT2']]
)

df = df.withColumn(
    'distance',
    haversine('LOCLONG_int', 'LOCLAT_int', 'LOCLONG2_int', 'LOCLAT2_int')
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks much!! Code looks good and runs well but for some reason when applying the method it is giving me this error: must be real number, not str Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in haversine
TypeError: must be real number, not str

Comment: I took the method from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points

Comment: `codefrom math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r`

Comment: @Ana did you convert the function to a UDF? put @F.udf above the line `def haversine(...)`