# Calculate the minimum distance to destinations for each origin in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, haversine

I have a list of origins and destinations along with their geo coordinates. I need to calculate the minimum distance for each origin to the destinations.

Below is my code:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from haversine import haversine_vector, Unit

data1 = [("A", (45.7597, 4.8422)), ("B", (46.7431, 5.8422))]
columns1 = ["Origin", "Origin_Geo"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns1)
data2 = [("Destin1", (48.8567, 2.3508)), ("Destin2", (40.7033962, -74.2351462))]
columns2 = ["Destination", "Destination_Geo"]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=columns2)

df = df1.crossJoin(df2)

df.withColumn(
    "Distance", haversine_vector(F.col("Origin_Geo"), F.col("Destination_Geo"))
).groupBy("Origin").agg(F.min("Distance").alias("Min_Distance")).show()
```

I got error like below:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

my question is:

1. it seems that there is something wrong with `withColumn('Distance',  haversine_vector(F.col('Origin_Geo'), F.col('Destination_Geo')))`.  I do not know why. (I'm new to  pyspark..)
2. I have a long list of origins and destinations (both over 30K).  Cross join generate numerous combinations of origins and destinations.  I wonder if there is any more efficient way to get the min distance?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why do you use `haversine_vector` instead of `haversine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the `haversine` function to a column where it should be applied to a tuple or an array.

If you want to use this lib, you need to create an UDF and to install the haversine package on all your spark nodes.

```py
from haversine import haversine
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

haversine_udf = F.udf(haversine, T.FloatType())

df.withColumn(
    "Distance", haversine_udf(F.col("Origin_Geo"), F.col("Destination_Geo"))
).groupBy("Origin").agg(F.min("Distance").alias("Min_Distance")).show()
```

If you cannot install the package on every node, then you can simply use the built-in version of the function (cf. [Haversine Formula in Python (Bearing and Distance between two GPS points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points)) - ***The formula is heavily dependent on the radius of the earth you choose***

```py
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

@F.udf(T.FloatType())
def haversine_udf(point1, point2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1 = point1
    lon2, lat2 = point2
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6372.8  # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r

df.withColumn(
    "Distance", haversine_udf(F.col("Origin_Geo"), F.col("Destination_Geo"))
).groupBy("Origin").agg(F.min("Distance").alias("Min_Distance")).show()
+------+------------+                                                           
|Origin|Min_Distance|
+------+------------+
|     B|   351.08905|
|     A|   392.32755|
+------+------------+
```

Comment: thank you so much!  Do you have any thoughts on my question #2?

Comment: @zesla cross joins are what they are. unfortunately, I do not know any way to reduce their cost.

Comment: @zesla in the original package, the radius of the earth is 6371.0088