# issues in creating a new column of tuple from two dataframe columns in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to create a column of tuple based on other two columns in spark dataframe.

```
data = [ ('A', 4,5 ),
        ('B', 6, 9 )
       ]
columns= ["id","val1", "val2"]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)

sdf.withColumn('values', F.struct(F.col('val1'), F.col('val2')) ).show()
```

what I got is:

[image]

I need column `values` to be tuples. So instead of `{4,5}  {6,9}`,  I want `(4,5)  (6,9)`.  Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840563/how-to-return-a-tuple-type-in-a-udf-in-pyspark

Comment: Why do you need tuples ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the minimum distance to destinations for each origin in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614421/calculate-the-minimum-distance-to-destinations-for-each-origin-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how spark works.

Spark is a framework that is developped in Scala, based on Java JVM. It is not Python.
Pyspark is a set of API that calls the Scala methods to execute Spark but in Python language.

Therefore, Python types such as `tuple` do not exists in Spark. You have to use either :

- `Struct` which is close to Python `dict`
- `Array` which are the equivalent of `list` (probably what you need if you want something close to `tuple`).

The real question is **Why do you need tuples?**

---

**EDIT**: According to your comment, you need `tuples` because you want to use `haversine`. But if you use list (or Spark Array) for example, it works perfectly fine :

```py
# Use the haversine doc example but with list

lyon = [45.7597, 4.8422]
paris = [48.8567, 2.3508]

haversine(lyon, paris)
> 392.2172595594006
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The reason I need tuple is in my real case, I want to haversine function (from haversine module) to calculate distance between two locations, which require the input as a pair of tuples with lat and lon.  e.g.   `haversine ( (45.7597, 4.8422), (46.7431, 5.8422) )`. I actually have two columns of `values`, which I need to calculate distance.  Could yo advice what I should do ?

Comment: @zesla Can you update your question with [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Show what you did, what is going wrong, with code and error message.

Comment: @zesla I added an edit with array/list working perfectly fine. So update your question with your actual code/problem, that'd avoid [XY_problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)