# How to make a column in data frame as a function of two others column in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the data frame that have 4 columns two first have coordinations of first point x1, y1 and two second have coordinations of second one x1, y2. I need to calculate distance between these points and fill it into other column. To calculate distance I use geopy.distance.geodesic and I need to do it fast so I don't want to do it in cycle. Can I do something like that in pandas?
`df['distance'] = df['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'].map(lambda x,y,z,w = geodesic((x, y), (z, w)))`

Comment: Pass the relevant series directly to a Haversine function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722117/2741091. Otherwise apply your `geopy` function.

Comment: your line of code should work. Did you try it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I understand that you want to calculate distance on each row values without looping. You can use apply() ([look at documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)) using a lambda function as shown below:

```
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda row: geodesic((row['x1'], row['y1']), (row['x2'], row['y2'])), axis=1)
```

This code applies lambda function to each pair of points on each row and stores the results into new column 'distance' on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple fields of a dataframe row,
you need to use something like:

df['dx'] = df.apply(lambda row:dx_function(row),axis=1)

in your main program, where 'row' is being passed
to function dx_function.

In the function dx_function, use:

x1 = row['x1']
y1 = row['y1']

The function would return the result.

If you wanted to modify just one field, use:

df['name'] = df['name'].map(lambda x: x.lower())

This would change the text in the column 'name' to lower case.

Hope this helps.